# How to use kotlin.Pair with databinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

It is working fine as long as I am using the data model with two fields.

But when I am trying to use kotlin. Pair it is failing to build and giving nit informative error :

```
....\DataBinderMapperImpl.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
import .....databinding.ItemCurrencyBindingImpl;


  symbol:   class ItemCurrencyBindingImpl

  location: package ......databinding
```

Xml code :

```
    <variable
        name="currency"
        type="kotlin.Pair"/>
</data>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/currency_dropdown_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center|start"
    android:padding="@dimen/currency_dropdown_padding"
    android:text="@{currency.first}"
    app:drawableEnd="@{currency.second}"
    app:drawableSize="@{@dimen/currency_dropdown_image_size}"
    tools:text="@string/pound"/></layout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the import of the type pair to your data section, and also declare the type of the elements of the pair.

If you  `currency` type is `Pair<String, Int>` you can declare it like this:

```
<import type="kotlin.Pair"/>
<variable name="currency" type="Pair&lt;String, Int&gt;"/>
```

Comment: Can be used without import of the type - ```<variable name="currency" type="kotlin.Pair&lt;String, Integer&gt;" />```, also, there should be Integer, not Int